# Google Cloud Storage - ACL change during operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, acl

I am wondering, what happens with GCS operation when ACL rules change during execution.

Let's consider such a flow:

```
client1 ---->   upload file  ---> file uploading...... ---> [????]
               read-write ACL             read-only ACL
                                                    
   
  adm-client ---> request ACL change ---> ACL changed
                     (read-only)
```

What happens then? Does the file upload will be successful or not?
The case is that I would like to block uploading any files to the specified directory at a specified hour and I am wondering what will happen with operations that started right before ACL change.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Object uploads are atomic. You cannot change the ACL for an object while it is uploading. Additionally, you cannot even see (list, delete, etc.) an object until the upload completes.

Comment: But what if I change the rules for the directory, not the object directly?

Comment: Directories do not exist in Google Cloud Storage. What you think is a directory is the first part of the object name which is called the **prefix**. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

Comment: Let's say I am making such a rule: `resource.name.startWith("project/bucket/20201010/12")` (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#examples-resource). What if someone had the access but the rule has changed during the upload?

Comment: @Cililing the upload will complete if the ACL changed while uploading.

Comment: Instead of trying to find a theoretical situation, post a real problem that needs a solution that is on topic. Stack Overflow is not a chat box. Read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know the rules and in my opinion, the question is well-asked. The problem is clear and well described in the very first sentence of this question. If you don't know the answer just skip this question. If you have any idea to improve the clarity of this question you are allowed to do so.

Comment: My first comment provided the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Posting @JohnHanley's comment as the answer for visibility.

Object uploads are atomic. You cannot change the ACL for an object while it is uploading. Additionally, you cannot even see (list, delete, etc.) an object until the upload completes.

For example, if you create a rule like [`resource.name.startWith("project/bucket/20201010/12")`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#examples-resource) and someone had access but the rule has changed during the upload, the upload will still complete.